# Using pandas, how do I subsample a large DataFrame by group in an efficient manner?

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas, data.table

I am trying to subsample rows of a DataFrame according to a grouping.  Here is an example.  Say I define the following data:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({'group1' : ["a","b","a","a","b","c","c","c","c",
                            "c","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"],
                'group2' : [1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6,5,4,1,2,3,4,3,2,1],
                'value'  : ["apple","pear","orange","apple",
                            "banana","durian","lemon","lime",
                            "raspberry","durian","peach","nectarine",
                            "banana","lemon","guava","blackberry","grape"]})
```

If I group by `group1` and `group2`, then the number of rows in each group is here:

```
In [190]: df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'].agg({'count':len})
Out[190]: 
      count
a  1  2    
   2  1    
   3  2    
   4  1    
b  1  2    
   2  2    
   3  1    
   4  1    
c  3  1    
   4  1    
   5  2    
   6  1
```

(If there is an even more concise way to compute that, please tell.)

I now want to construct a DataFrame that has one randomly selected row from each group.  My proposal is to do it like so:

```
In [215]: from random import choice
In [216]: grouped = df.groupby(['group1','group2'])
In [217]: subsampled = grouped.apply(lambda x: df.reindex(index=[choice(range(len(x)))]))
In [218]: subsampled.index = range(len(subsampled))
In [219]: subsampled
Out[219]: 
    group1  group2  value
0   b       2       pear 
1   a       1       apple
2   b       2       pear 
3   a       1       apple
4   a       1       apple
5   a       1       apple
6   a       1       apple
7   a       1       apple
8   a       1       apple
9   a       1       apple
10  a       1       apple
11  a       1       apple
```

which works.  However, my real data has about 2.5 million rows and 12 columns.  If I do this the dirty way by building my own data structures, I can complete this operation in a matter of seconds.  However, my implementation above does not finish within 30 minutes (and does not appear to be memory-limited).  As a side note, when I tried implementing this in R, I first tried `plyr`, which also did not finish in a reasonable amount of time; however, a solution using `data.table` finished very rapidly.

How do I get this to work rapidly with `pandas`?  I want to love this package, so please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested with apply, it seems that when there are many sub groups, it's very slow. the groups attribute of grouped is a dict, you can choice index directly from it:

```
subsampled = df.ix[(choice(x) for x in grouped.groups.itervalues())]
```

EDIT: As of pandas version 0.18.1, `itervalues` no longer works on groupby objects - you can just use `.values`:

```
subsampled = df.ix[(choice(x) for x in grouped.groups.values())]
```

Comment: I replied on the pystatsmodels mailing list about this. I came up with the same solution you suggested-- being the package author I don't know of a better way =)

Comment: @wesm, I was just about to cross-post your answer here as well.  Thanks everyone!